I am trying to enter strings into 2D array using functions. I have written a code but I understand the problem with it
I have written the code...It takes input properly but during runtime, it gives incomplete values.
please help.
#include <stdio.h>
int input(char str[5][100],int n)
{
    int ch, i=0,j;
    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        while ((ch=getchar()) !='\n')
        {
            if (i<n)
            {
                str[j][i++] = ch;
            }
        }
        str[j][i]='\0';
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    
    char str[5][100];
    int n=input(str,10);
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",str[i]);
    
    }

    return 0;
}

I have tried the following:
INPUT
water
newwater
camouflag
norwaya
poliski
OUTPUT
water@

It's a time as good as any to get started with debugging. Advanced C developers would use a debugger such as gdb but this can be a lot to take in for newcomers. Try regularly printing the values of variables to log their state (using printf() for instance). Eventually, you'll find the silly mistake you've made in the function input().

The index i starts at 0 for each call to the function. Should it not restart at 0 for each of the strings?


You never reset i to zero in the loop, hence the bug.
There's no point in returning anything from this function as written, what does that number even mean? The number of total characters entered, the longest substring, what?
Don't invent your own obscure coding styles, but use the name i for the left-most dimension of the array which is convention, then j and so on.

Fixed code might look something like this:
void input (char str[5][100], int n)
{
    int ch;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; (ch=getchar())!='\n' && j<n; j++)
        {
            str[i][j] = ch;
        }
        str[i][j]='\0';
    }
}


0 assigned to i inside of the for loop.
#include <stdio.h>

int input(char str[5][100], int n) {
    int ch, i, j;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        i = 0;
        while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
            if (i < n) {
                str[j][i++] = ch;
            }
        }
        str[j][i] = '\0';
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char str[5][100];
    int n = input(str, 100); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}


Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[answer]". Then come back and [edit] your answer to provide more details what the error is and how you resolved it. (Disclaimer: I did not vote down.)
